# How to convert timestamp value to number and then convert to human readable

Tags: jq

I have a string timestamp key I need to convert to a number because `strftime` throws an error that it needs to be a number.

`journalctl -n1 --output=json | jq '.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber |= (. / 1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d")), .MESSAGE'`

but I get invalid path expression errors.  I assume I don't have the syntax down right.

I ultimately want to display key `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` in human readable format and key `MESSAGE`.

Comment: Do you have any example input that we could test with (output from `journalctl -n1 --output=json`)?  You can't modify the result of `tonumber` with `|=` (the left-hand side of that operator must be a path within the document).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what your intention with `|=` is here.

It could work like this:

```
$ journalctl -n1 --output=json |
    jq '(.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber/1000000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), .MESSAGE'
"2023-11-11 21:44:27"
"[session uid=1000 pid=1420] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'gvfs-daemon.service': Unit gvfs-daemon.service is masked."
```

Or formatted / raw output:

```
$ journalctl -n1 --output=json | 
    jq -r '(.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber/1000000 | strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]: ")) + .MESSAGE'
[2023-11-11 21:44:27]: [session uid=1000 pid=1420] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'gvfs-daemon.service': Unit gvfs-daemon.service is masked.
```

Comment: I don't know what `|=` is.   Your solution worked.

Comment: @deanresin It's the "update operator". It modifies the path to its left with the expression to its right: `.thing |= tonumber` (the same as `.thing = (.thing | tonumber)`).

Comment: Using `strflocaltime("%F %T %Z")` would give you the same output format for the timestamp as with in the `short-full` format from `journalctl`, and using that with the message in an array passed through `@tsv` would give you nice tab-delimited output that would allow you to easily post-process the messages afterwards by message or by human-readable timestamp. The only difference between that and the `short-full` format would be the exclusion of the systemd service name and the fact that the two fields woul be tab-delimited.